# Проблема с импортом DRF.responce - python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

*Я, копаясь в своём ПК, нашёл свой старый проект, который использует Django REST Framework. Но при его настройке возникла проблема с импортом, которую не могу решить.*

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.responce import Responce
from rest_framework.view import APIView
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Blog, Tag
from .serializer import BlogSerializer
from .forms import UserLoginForm, UserRegisterForm
# Create your views here.

class BlogAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Responce({'result': 'True'})


def main_render(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html')


def blog_render(request):
    return render(request, 'main/blog.html', {'blog': Blog.objects.all().order_by('-id')})


def contacts_render(request):
    return render(request, 'main/contacts.html')


def for_posts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Blog()
        form.post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        form.title = request.POST.get('title')
        form.file = request.POST.get('image')
        form.description = request.POST.get('description')
        form.date = request.POST.get('date')
        form.user = request.POST.get('user')
        form.save()
        return redirect('blog')

    return render(request, 'main/addpost.html')

def blog_id(request, id_blog : int):
    id_setting = get_object_or_404(Blog, id = id_blog)

    return render(request, 'main/blog_id.html', {'id_setting': id_setting, 'id': id_blog, 'blog': Blog.objects.all()})
```

> Вывод в консоль:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\letsp\OneDrive\Документы\tahysgyr.dev\tahysgyr\tahysgyr\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from main import views
  File "C:\Users\letsp\OneDrive\Документы\tahysgyr.dev\tahysgyr\main\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework.responce import Responce
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.responce'
C:\Users\letsp\OneDrive\Документы\tahysgyr.dev\tahysgyr\tahysgyr\settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\letsp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\letsp\OneDrive\Документы\tahysgyr.dev\tahysgyr\tahysgyr\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from main import views
  File "C:\Users\letsp\OneDrive\Документы\tahysgyr.dev\tahysgyr\main\views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_framework.responce import Responce
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.responce'
```

Модуль `rest_framework` установлен.

Comment: Через эту команду устанавливали? ```pip install djangorestframework```

Comment: да, извините, что не ответил)

Comment: Сейчас запускается проект?

Comment: нет, выводит ту же ошибку